# How can I remove a dimension from a large array in R?

Tags: r

I have two large arrays of data that I need to be the same dimensions to perform further analysis.

One array has 3 dimensions, one array has 4. The 4th dimension in the second array is not useful and I need to remove this data from the array. What function will do this?

[[image: snip of the array data structure]]

I have tried array_pop but this function is not present in base RStudio? Is there a library I can install which will let me use something like array_pop?

Comment: R ≠ RStudio. Anyway, where did you get the idea from that `array_pop` exists? I only know this function from PHP, where it does something completely different.

Comment: If you only want the first "slice" of the 4D array, you can do `err_mod_pres[,,,1]`.

Comment: If you want all the slices in a list, you can do `asplit(err_mod_pres, 4)`

Comment: `4th dimension in the second array is not useful` taken literally means that you are discarding over 91% of the data, is that correct? Another way to look at it is that you want to compare all of `err_obv_pres` with only one "hyperplane" of `err_mod_pres`. For that, use AllanCameron's method, choosing `[,,,1]` or one of the other 12 possibles. By default in R, when you reduce one of the dimensions to 1, R will automatically remove that dimension.

Comment: Apologies if my question is clear. I just need the two arrays to be conformable to perform further analysis. As they have different length of elements, I cannot do this at the moment. Is it possible instead to add a fourth dimension onto the 3-element array to allow this?

Comment: Until you show us *exactly* what you intend to do, we can't give a quality answer.  You may need to learn about `[ , , ,k ,drop=TRUE]`    or you may simply need to write a loop, taking one 'slice' at a time.